# CSS animation based on speed and not time?

Tags: css, animation

I have the following CSS animation:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  font: 300 30px/1 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  animation: 60s credits linear;
}

@keyframes credits {
  0% {
    top: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    transform: translateY(-110%);
  }
}
```

I need to change this to go based on 'speed' rather than 'time'.

The content I am animating can change in size by over 1000%. Animating the content in a small size can make it scroll very slow. The opposite is true.

Can anyone think of any solutions I may have looked over?

Comment: How does the content change in size? Do you have a demo anywhere?

Comment: I add text to a div and scroll like movie credits, but the amount of names, each on their own line, can be one to several thousand.

I edited this codepen to have the same animation CSS https://codepen.io/webdevhehehe/pen/oWBZYe

You can see it speeding up or slowing down greatly depending on the amount of content in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, but if the content is based on viewport size you could update `animation-duration` in media queries to increase/decrease the value.